# CSS and HTML for menubar

Tags: html, css, navbar, menubar

I simply need each entire button to be clickable as opposed to just the text when you hover over it. It was working before but I messes with some stuff and now its back to only reading the text as the `<a href`.

there's what I got.(p.s. i'm still new to this kind of teaching myself as I go along)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
#menubar {
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    background: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: all .25s;
    -webkit-transition: all .25s; 
    background: linear-gradient(silver, black);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(silver,black);
}

#menubar:hover {
    width: 225px;
    background: linear-gradient(lightskyblue, blue);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(lightskyblue,blue);
}
/* Code to make whole menu bar div clickable */
.default-link{
  position:absolute; 
  width:200px;
  height:50px;
}  

#menubar ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0 50px;
}

#menubar ul li a {
    color: white;
    font-size:25px;
    text-decoration:none;
    position:inherit;
}

.auto-style1 {
    margin-left: 0px;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<!--Left Side Menu Bar Code-->
<div id="menubar">
    <ul>
        <li class="auto-style1" style="width: 137px">
            <a class='default-link' href='javascript:void(0)'             onclick='window.location = "#"' style="left: 11px; top: 16px; width: 200px;     height: 50px">
            Menu 1</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="menubar">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a class='default-link' href='javascript:void(0)'     onclick='window.location = "#"' style="left: 11px; top: 66px; width: 200px; height: 50px">
        Menu 2</a>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>

<div id="menubar">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a class='default-link' href='javascript:void(0)' onclick='window.location = "#"' style="left: 11px; top: 116px; width: 200px; height: 50px">
            Menu 3</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="menubar">
<ul>
    <li>
        <a class='default-link' href='javascript:void(0)' onclick='window.location = "#"' style="left: 11px; top: 166px; width: 200px; height: 50px">
        Menu 4</a>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>

<div id="menubar">
<ul>
    <li>
        <a class='default-link' href='javascript:void(0)' onclick='window.location = "#"' style="left: 11px; top: 216px; width: 200px; height: 50px">
        Menu 5</a>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>

<div id="menubar">
<ul>
    <li>
        <a class='default-link' href='javascript:void(0)' onclick='window.location = "#"' style="left: 11px; top: 266px; width: 200px; height: 50px">
        Menu 6</a>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: id="menubar" -  id attribute specifies a unique id for an HTML element (the value must be unique within the HTML document).

Answer (score 1):

code you have shared need lots of cleanup .. Id is unique identifier you can not use it repeatedly. Moreover you can optimize your code there are many unwanted `div` and `ul` tags.

Please check this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Bhagya/ppdLL99s/).

```css
.menubar{
  padding:0;
}
.menubar li{
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  background: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all .25s;
  -webkit-transition: all .25s;
  background: linear-gradient(silver, black);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(silver, black);
}
.menubar li:hover {
  width: 225px;
  background: linear-gradient(lightskyblue, blue);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(lightskyblue, blue);
}

/* Code to make whole menu bar div clickable */
.default-link {
  position:absolute;
  width:200px;
  height:50px;
  color: white;
  font-size:25px;
  text-decoration:none; 
}
.menubar li{
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0 50px;
  position:relative;
}
.auto-style1 {
  margin-left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<!--Left Side Menu Bar Code-->
<ul class="menubar">
  <li class="auto-style1"> <a class='default-link' href='javascript:void(0)' onclick='window.location = "#"'>
    Menu 1</a>
  </li>
  <li> <a class='default-link' href='javascript:void(0)' onclick='window.location = "#"'>
    Menu 2</a>

  </li>
  <li> <a class='default-link' href='javascript:void(0)' onclick='window.location = "#"'>
    Menu 3</a>

  </li>
  <li> <a class='default-link' href='javascript:void(0)' onclick='window.location = "#"'>
    Menu 4</a>

  </li>
  <li> <a class='default-link' href='javascript:void(0)' onclick='window.location = "#"'>
    Menu 5</a>

  </li>
  <li> <a class='default-link' href='javascript:void(0)' onclick='window.location = "#"'>
    Menu 6</a>

  </li>
</ul>
```

Hope it will help you.